# Representing hyperlinks differently in a single pdf file

Tags: hyperref, lyx, links

Can someone tell me how to color/represent (only internal) hyperlinks in a pdf differently (preferably just by using LyX,i.e. without diving deeper into pure latex) ? For example I would like the links from the table of contents to the separate sections my pdf to be put in a blue box, but all the other links (links to formulas or footnotes) to be green-coloured text.

My problem is, if I set a color and a "style"(in a box/text-colored) **all** links are like that and I see no way of differentiating between them.

My version of LyX is 2.

Comment: Did you try putting something like this `\hypersetup{linkcolor=darkred,citecolor=darkblue,urlcolor=black}` ?

Comment: See now also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46513/9237.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t know `Lyx`, so I can only show you a pure `LaTeX` solution:
You can use `\hypersetup` several times:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin,english]{babel} % needed for "blindtext",
                                  % "english" is the active language
\usepackage{blindtext,lipsum,kantlipsum}

\usepackage[%
  colorlinks=true,% 
  linkcolor=red,%
  linktoc=all,%
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\hypersetup{%
  linkcolor=blue,%
}

\section{Package \texttt{blindtext}}

\subsection{English blindtext}\label{btext-en}
See also package \hyperref[klipsum]{\ttfamily kantlipsum}.
\medskip

\blindtext[1]

\subsection{Latin blindtext}\label{btext-la}
Compare package \hyperref[lipsum]{\ttfamily lipsum}.
\medskip

{\selectlanguage{latin}% note the grouping
\blindtext[1]}

\newpage

\hypersetup{%
  linkcolor=green,%
}

\section{Package \texttt{kantlipsum}}\label{klipsum}
See also package \hyperref[btext-en]{\texttt{blindtext} with English text}.
\medskip

\kant[1]

\section{Package \texttt{lipsum}}\label{lipsum}
Compare package \hyperref[btext-la]{\texttt{blindtext} with pseudo-Latin text}.
\medskip

{\selectlanguage{latin}% actually not needed here
\lipsum[1]}% note the grouping again

\end{document}
```

First I’ve defined red link colour inside the `hyperref` package options (the two others are for better recognizability). This could have been done in a first separate `\hypersetup`, too.

After the table of contents I’ve put one `\hypersetup` for blue link colour, and later I set another one, just to show you the opportunity.

Comment: Thanks, your solution **almost** worked for me. What didn't worked yet, is making a box around the links in the TOC, but not around all the others. If I add \hypersetup{colorlinks=false} before the \begin{document} line, the **all** my links don't have boxes (and subsequent \hypersetup commands can't change this - although they can change the color of the box...). The same goes for no "\hypersetup{colorlinks=false}" and the  "=true" value, the same behaviour holds: Either all or none. Changing the colours works fine though. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @user10324: Sorry, the part with the box I’ve overlooked. I have no idea, how this could be done. But why do you want boxes in the toc, and later coloured links? You could also change the option `linktoc` or replace it by `linktocpage`. See for that in the README.pdf of `hyperref` documentation. (How about `linkcolor=black` for the toc?)