# How to have multiple link styles with hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, pdftex

I have `hyperref`s in many places in my program. Part of it is in normal text, which I have styled with `\hypersetup`.

I also have some listings inside which I use `hyperref`. The problem is, the `listings` has its own style, so I want to have a different style for `hyperref`.

Is such a thing possible? Can you have two `hyperref`s in the same document with different styles?

Comment: Do you mean different link colors?

Comment: @Dr.HarishKumar For example. Or any other style related stuff. Let's say, one `hyperref` that has `colorlinks` `true` and the other `false`.

Comment: This is IMHO a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45560/representing-hyperlinks-differently-in-a-single-pdf-file, but my answer there lacks the part of `\Hy@DisableOption{...}` as in Ulrike’s answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hyperref disables some options (with `\Hy@DisableOption{...}`) in the package, other at the begin of the document. These options (including `colorlinks)`can't be changed in the mid of the document.

But other options can be changed without problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\hypersetup{urlcolor= red}
\url{test}

\hypersetup{urlcolor= green}
\url{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! I didn't know `hypersetup` could be written in the document body.

Comment: Quick side question, is it possible to tell `hyperref` to have `urlcolor` equal to whatever the text itself is? So its color would follow the color of the the text. If the link is in some red text, it would be red and if in green text it would be green?

Comment: @Shahbaz: Yes, that’s exactly the effect of `colorlinks=true` (Ulrike used the equivalent short form). Or did you mean something like `\definecolor{textcolor}{named}{black} \color{textcolor} \hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=textcolor}`?

Comment: @speravir: I mean something like this: `\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=blue}` in the preamble, and then later something like: `\hypersetup{urlcolor=follow-text}` and then have `\color{red} some text \url{this url will be red} some text \color{green} some text \url{this url will be green} some text \hypersetup{urlcolor=blue}`. Of course, everywhere else in the document, the url would be blue

Comment: In fact, it's no big deal, but if there is such an option it would be easier for me

Comment: @Shahbaz: I can’t help you here. Please ask this as an separate question, but explain there, what the reason is for such an unconventional wish :-).

Comment: @speravir, alright, will do!