# Using \hyperlink to link text to page with an implicit page anchor not known in advance

Tags: hyperref

`hyperref` provides the command `\hyperlink`, with syntax:

```
\hyperlink{name}{text}
```

where *name* is the name of a hypertext object, and *text* is used as the link to jump to the defined mark. Page anchors, e.g., `page.12`, can also be used as hypertext objects. For example,

```
Click \hyperlink{page.23}{here} to jump to page 23.
```

This was proposed by Martin Scharrer as a solution to  [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19412/linking-a-text-to-a-page-by-page-number/).

I would  like to link a string of text to a page (by page number) using `\hyperlink`, but being able to refer to an implicit page anchor `page.<number>` whose ''number'' is not known in advance. That is, use a value of the counter `page`, which is only set later in the document, in the argument of `\hyperlink`.

Here's a hypothetical solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pageanchor]{hyperref} % option is the default anyway

%% Martin Scharrer's patch for hyperref
%% available at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19416/9237
\makeatletter
\let\orig@Hy@EveryPageAnchor\Hy@EveryPageAnchor
\def\Hy@EveryPageAnchor{%
    \begingroup
    \hypersetup{pdfview=Fit}%
    \orig@Hy@EveryPageAnchor
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother 

\def\getpageref{???}   % \getpageref extracts the numeric value of \pageref{key}
                       % for use in the first argument of \hyperlink

\begin{document}

See
\hyperlink{page.\getpageref{lkd}}{this page}
for further clarification.

\newpage

This is the linked page.\label{lkd}

\end{document}
```

I know how to achieve a *similar* solution by simply using `\label` and then `\pageref` (or `\autopageref`), but I am interested in making use of a `hyperref` patch proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19412/linking-a-text-to-a-page-by-page-number/) by Martin to make all page anchors be displayed in full page mode. (This patch only seems to work with `\hyperlink`.)

Comment: Regarding your question: Take a look at `cleveref`, which, when used, should BTW loaded _after_ `hyperref`.

Comment: Steffen, thanks for the suggestion, I'll start using it from now on. However, it is my understanding that none of the commands provided by `cleveref` are part of the solution to my question.

Comment: The option `pageanchor` in `hyperref` is true by default, so I left it out in my answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can label the page you want to link to using the normal `\label` command, and extract its page number with `\getpagerefnumber` from the [`refcount`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/refcount) package to use it in the `\hyperlink` (the "normal" LaTeX macro `\pageref` doesn't work here, as it is not expandable).

#### A small example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage[pageanchor]{hyperref}

%% Martin's patch for hyperref
\makeatletter
\let\orig@Hy@EveryPageAnchor\Hy@EveryPageAnchor
\def\Hy@EveryPageAnchor{%
    \begingroup
    \hypersetup{pdfview=Fit}%
    \orig@Hy@EveryPageAnchor
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}

See
\hyperlink{page.\getpagerefnumber{mypage}}{this page}
for further clarification.
\clearpage

\dots
\clearpage

This is the linked page.\label{mypage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But `\hyperlink` needs a `\hypertarget`, or am I wrong? See my answer.

Comment: @Speravir Generally it does, however the `pageanchor` option of `hyperref` (which is active by default) adds the necessary anchors automatically, so my solution works without explicitly creating these. See the [`hyperref` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/hyperref) for more information.

Comment: @Speravir Look for the description of the `pageanchor` option. Even more information can be found in the [commented `hyperref` sources](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/hyperref.pdf#page=179), especially p. 179f, where you can see that if `pageanchor` is activated, `\hyper@@anchor{page.\@the@H@page}\relax` is executed, which is the same as `\hypertarget{page.<page number>}{}`.

Comment: I still don't get it, it's far from what I'm able to understand, now. Nonetheless a suggestion: Add some explanation into your answer and we delete our comments.

Answer (score 3):

I tried last night some things, but got only errors, as I played with `\pageref*`. But diabonas’ answer gave me the decisive hint. So here’s my solution *without* `\hyperlink`. It uses the alternative definition `\hyperref{URL}{category}{label}{text}` instead with `category` = “page”. It’s especially useful for external resources (PDF in external `URL` needs of course page anchors, and it works, as far as I know, only with the browser plugin version of Adobe Reader). In my MWE the `URL` is set to `./\jobname.pdf`, what will be converted into the local PDF file. It works exactly as wanted by the OP.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin,english]{babel} % needed for "blindtext",
                                  % "english" is the active language
\usepackage{blindtext,lipsum,kantlipsum} % just for the examples

\usepackage{refcount}% from "oberdiek" bundle

\usepackage[%
  colorlinks=true,%
  linkcolor=green,%
%  filecolor=cyan,% it's the default
]{hyperref}

%%% Patch from Martin Scharrer
%%% cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19416/9237
\makeatletter
\let\orig@Hy@EveryPageAnchor\Hy@EveryPageAnchor
\def\Hy@EveryPageAnchor{%
    \begingroup
    \hypersetup{pdfview=Fit}%
    \orig@Hy@EveryPageAnchor
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

%%% \mypageref{<label>}{some linked text}
\newcommand{\mypageref}[2]{\hyperref{./\jobname.pdf}{page}{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\section{Package \texttt{blindtext}}

\subsection{English blindtext}\label{btext-en}
See also package \hyperref[klipsum]{\ttfamily kantlipsum} on
\mypageref{klipsum}{next page}.

\medskip

\blindtext[1]

\subsection{Latin blindtext}\label{btext-la}
Compare package \hyperref[lipsum]{\ttfamily lipsum} on
\mypageref{lipsum}{page \pageref*{lipsum}}.

\medskip

\begin{otherlanguage}{latin}
\blindtext[1]
\end{otherlanguage}

\newpage

\section{Package \texttt{kantlipsum}}\label{klipsum}
See also package \hyperref[btext-en]{\texttt{blindtext} with English text} on
\mypageref{btext-en}{previous page}.

\medskip

\kant[1]

\section{Package \texttt{lipsum}}\label{lipsum}
Compare package \hyperref[btext-la]{\texttt{blindtext} with pseudo-Latin text} on
\mypageref{btext-la}{page \pageref*{btext-la}}.

\medskip

\begin{otherlanguage}{latin}
\lipsum[1]
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

<sub>MWE happily stolen from myself: [Representing hyperlinks differently in a single pdf file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45560/representing-hyperlinks-differently-in-a-single-pdf-file/45582#45582).</sub>

Comment: The cyan-colored "page 2", "page 1", "next page", and "previous page" do not act as links! (And why do they get colored if not?)