# In TeXnic center, is there a command can I use to point to exactly the place in the article where I made a LaTeX error?

Tags: errors, compiling, texniccenter

I know this probably could be a very elementary question, but I am a very beginner in LaTeX. I am using LaTeX in windows on a PC. I am using teXniC center and MikTeX for writing a laTeX article. When I selected " Build and View " option in order to compile, it shows me the errors. I have some elementary questions :

1) It always shows the signs for " go to previous error / next error ", but is there a sign for " first error, second error" etc according to the order in which they occurred in the article ?

2) Also, for the errors, it is showing : 1.67, 1.44 etx...what numbers are they ?

3) Also, is there a pointer that would go to the place in the article where exactly I made the error and point it right there ?

I know these are very elementary questions, but I would be grateful if you could tell me the answers ! Have a great day !

Answer (score 3):

<sup>*“Three questions at a time – that’s truly impossible!”*</sup>

*Note: I use TeXnicCenter version 2.0 alpha4.*

Regarding 1.) No, there is no button or key shortcut, as far as I see. But you can navigate in the output window with cursors or with the keys <kbd>PgUp</kbd> / <kbd>PgDn</kbd> or even better with the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> and then use the error buttons or the appropriate <kbd>F9</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> keys. See also the window, that you get with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. <sub>Note for users with non-english keyboards: If you have a <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key – it does *not* work!</sub>

Reg 2.) You mix up “1” and “l”. It’s the abbreviation for “line”, not the cipher.

Reg. 3.) Don’t blame TeXnicCenter here: Usually it sets the cursor in the line, where the output routine of *LaTeX* (or whatever you used) the error noticed. It will be the line you see in the output window. That the causing error sometimes is hard to catch, is known in (La)TeX, compare for instance the answers to [Documents with typical LaTeX errors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33468/9237) or take a look on this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin,english]{babel} % needed for "blindtext",
                                  % "english" is the active language
\usepackage{blindtext,lipsum} % just for the examples

\usepackage{refcount}

\usepackage[%
  colorlinks=true,%
]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\mypageref}[2]{\hyperref{./\jobname.pdf}{page}{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{#2}}
% \mypageref{<label>}{some linked text}

\begin{document}

\section{Package \texttt{blindtext} with Latin blindtext}\label{btext-la}
Compare package \hyperref[lipsum]{\ttfamily lipsum} on
\mypageref{{lipsum}page \pageref*{lipsum}}.
% no error with correct brace placement:
%\mypageref{lipsum}{page \pageref*{lipsum}}.

\medskip

\begin{otherlanguage}{latin}
\blindtext[1]
\end{otherlanguage}

\newpage

\section{Package \texttt{lipsum}}\label{lipsum}
Compare package \hyperref[btext-la]{\texttt{blindtext} with pseudo-Latin text} on
\mypageref{btext-la}{page \pageref*{btext-la}.

\medskip

\begin{otherlanguage}{latin}
\lipsum[1]
\end{otherlanguage}}

\end{document}
```

<sub>(Code originally from [Using \hyperlink to link text to page with an implicit page anchor not known in advance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55560/using-hyperlink-to-link-text-to-a-page-by-page-number-whose-number-is-not-kno/55657#55657))</sub>