# Referencing an article from a beamer document with xr-hyper

Tags: beamer, hyperref, xr

I'm trying to link to a label in an article from a beamer file.
The reference itself works fine, but the hyperlink doesn't.
It gets defaulted to page 1 of the beamer file.

This is the article:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{section}\label{target}
\end{document}
```

This is the beamer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}

\externaldocument[article-]{article}[article.pdf]

\begin{document}
see \ref{article-target}
\end{document}
```

It works fine when not using the beamer class.

Comment: See here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71307/hyperref-to-external-pdf-that-will-open-at-particular-label. That combination works. Maybe you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: @cacamailg That might be possible, but that, in effect, means completely re-implementing the features of xr-hyper, just because beamer messes with the ref-functionality.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `beamer` requests `hyperref` not to load fully, and so `hyperref`'s `\ref` (and support commands) are not used. Instead, `beamer` tries to emulate the behaviour of `hyperref`'s `\ref` in terms of link support, but does not attempt to emulate the *external link* support.

I'm sure the following is really bad and will break lots of things, but one can re-enable `hyperref`'s `\ref` handling manually in `beamer`. But presumably `beamer` doesn't use `hyperref`'s version for good reason, so be warned!

At the very least, this also changes `\pageref` to use links.

Here goes:

```
\RequirePackage{xr-hyper}% need to load before hyperref, therefore need to load before beamer
\documentclass{beamer}

\errorcontextlines\maxdimen

%%%% [Referencing an article from a beamer document with xr-hyper](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127495)
\makeatletter
% undo beamer's changes to \ref, leaving us with hyperref's version
\AtBeginDocument
{
    \let\ref=\beamer@origref
}
% actually use hyperref's changes to commands used by \ref
% that were not loaded due to implicit=false
% these are copied from hyperref.sty
\let\real@setref\@setref
\def\@setref#1#2#3{% csname, extract group, refname
  \ifx#1\relax
    \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
    \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
    \@latex@warning{%
      Reference `#3' on page \thepage \space undefined%
    }%
  \else
    \expandafter\Hy@setref@link#1\@empty\@empty\@nil{#2}%
  \fi
}
\def\Hy@setref@link#1#2#3#4#5#6\@nil#7{%
  \begingroup
    \toks0={\hyper@@link{#5}{#4}}%
    \toks1=\expandafter{#7{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
      \the\toks0 {\the\toks1 }%
    }%
  \x
}
\def\@pagesetref#1#2#3{% csname, extract macro, ref
  \ifx#1\relax
    \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
    \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
    \@latex@warning{%
      Reference `#3' on page \thepage \space undefined%
    }%
  \else
    \protect\hyper@@link
      {\expandafter\@fifthoffive#1}%
      {page.\expandafter\@secondoffive#1}%
      {\expandafter\@secondoffive#1}%
  \fi
}
\def\HyRef@StarSetRef#1{%
  \begingroup
    \Hy@safe@activestrue
    \edef\x{#1}%
    \@onelevel@sanitize\x
    \edef\x{\endgroup
      \noexpand\HyRef@@StarSetRef
        \expandafter\noexpand\csname r@\x\endcsname{\x}%
    }%
  \x
}
\def\HyRef@@StarSetRef#1#2#3{%
  \ifx#1\@undefined
    \let#1\relax
  \fi
  \real@setref#1#3{#2}%
}
\def\@refstar#1{%
  \HyRef@StarSetRef{#1}\@firstoffive
}
\def\@pagerefstar#1{%
  \HyRef@StarSetRef{#1}\@secondoffive
}
\def\@namerefstar#1{%
  \HyRef@StarSetRef{#1}\@thirdoffive
}
\makeatother
% end changes needed by [Referencing an article from a beamer document with xr-hyper](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127495)


\externaldocument[article-]{article}[article.pdf]

\begin{document}
see \ref{article-target} (or \ref*{article-target} without the link)
\end{document}
```