# xr can't find references in external document

Tags: pdftex, cross-referencing, xr

I tried to [use the xr package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14364/cross-referencing-between-different-files) to get cross-references between files.

My primary document is book.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Beginning}
\label{ch1}

Foo

\input{chapter2.tex}

\end{document}
```

book.tex includes chapter2.tex:

```
\chapter{End}
\label{ch2}

Bar
```

My secondary document is supplement.tex:

```
\documentclass{powerdot}

\usepackage{xr}

\externaldocument{book}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}{Slide Title}
Reference A: \ref{ch1} page \pageref{ch1}

Reference B: \ref{ch2} page \pageref{ch2}
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

book.tex compiles fine using `pdflatex book.tex` but when I `latex supplement.tex` I get stuck with

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `ch1' on page 1 undefined on input line 13.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `ch2' on page 1 undefined on input line 13.
```

All the files are in the same directory and I am running `pdflatex` and `latex` in that directory without using the -output-directory flag. I also tried the `xr-hyper` package.

What else do I need to do to make supplement.tex pick up the references from book.tex (and its included file chapter2.tex)?

Comment: There is no `\externaldocument` statement in your `supplement` file

Comment: The final problem is `beamer` since it does apparently not support `hyperref` in its full extent and redefines some features, e.g. see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127495/referencing-an-article-from-a-beamer-document-with-xr-hyper

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I changed to powerdot and got a very similar error. Please see my updated question, thank you.

Comment: If book.tex loads the **hyperref**-package, then it is required that supplement.tex does load the **hyperref**-package also and that supplement.tex does load the **xr-hyper**-package instead of the **xr**-package. (The **xr-hyper**-package must be loaded before the **hyperref**-package.)

Answer (score 1):

Current state of the art is that the `\label`-`\(page)ref`-mechanism of the **LaTeX2e**-kernel gets modified by the **hyperref**-package.

Thus—if book.tex loads the **hyperref**-package, then it is required that supplement.tex

1. does load the **hyperref**-package also.
2. does load the **xr-hyper**-package instead of the **xr**-package.
   (The **xr-hyper**-package must be loaded before the **hyperref**-package.)

(On the platform used by me (MiKTeX 2.9) the **powerdot**-class seems to work only when compiling in dvi-Mode, yielding a .dvi-file which causes MiKTeX' dvi-previewer YaP to crash but which can without problems be converted via dvips to a postscript-file which in turn can be converted via ps2pdf to a .pdf-file.)

book.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Beginning}
\label{ch1}

Foo

\input{chapter2.tex}

\end{document}
```

chapter2.tex:

```
\chapter{End}
\label{ch2}

Bar
```

supplement.tex:

```
\documentclass{powerdot}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\externaldocument{book}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}{Slide Title}
Reference A: \ref{ch1} page \pageref{ch1}

Reference B: \ref{ch2} page \pageref{ch2}
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

By the way: If you wish to use the **beamer**-class, this works as well using the **xr-hyper**-package instead of the **xr**-package.

In this case supplement.tex could look like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\externaldocument{book}

\begin{document}

Reference A: \ref{ch1} page \pageref{ch1}

Reference B: \ref{ch2} page \pageref{ch2}

\end{document}
```