# Hyperref not jumping to the top of the page

Tags: hyperref

I use the package [`hypperef`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and it is fine, but when I use this

```
\hyperlink{label}{go to bla bla}

\newpage

\hypertarger{label}{}

a lot of bla bla
```

then, when I click on `go to bla bla`, I don't arrive on the *real top* of the newpage but at the top of all my blabla-writting, which is an effect I don't like.

> Would you know how to jump to the real top of the newpage?

Comment: Your answer should be solved by following the suggestion in [Using `\hyperlink` to link text to page with an implicit page anchor not known in advance](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55560/5764). The idea would be to capture the page via a regular `\ref`, then convert it to a counter (with the aid of [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount)) and use this to reference the page anchor...

Comment: It works perfectly !