# Table of contents entries that jumps to top of the page

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, hyperref

I'm making a custom document without any chapters, sections, etc. But I also want a table of contents in my document, with entries that I define. So far, I have used

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{My entry}
```

and this creates an entry within my table of contents (`\tableofcontents`). But when I click one of these entries, the jump takes me to the exact location in the document where this phantom section was defined. Instead I want jumps that takes me to the top of that page. Ideally, the page should be jumped to and fit to screen (zoom out, typically) when I click the entry.

How can I add entries to the table of contents that *jumps to the top of the page* I want an entry for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will take you to the page anchor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\phantompageref}{\def\@currentHref{page.\@the@H@page}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\rule{1pt}{.4\textheight}

\phantompageref
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{My entry}

\rule{2pt}{.4\textheight}
\end{document}
```

---

This links to the very top of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\AddEverypageHook{\raisebox{1in}[0pt][0pt]{\hypertarget{pagetop.\thepage}{}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\phantompageref}{\def\@currentHref{pagetop.\thepage}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\rule{1pt}{.4\textheight}

\phantompageref
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{My entry}

\rule{2pt}{.4\textheight}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This takes me to a top of my document, not on the page I have `\phantompageref` together with `\addcontentsline`. And it will not jump to the page border of my document, instead it jumps to the top of my header on this page (refer to the line which 5 points to in this figure: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Page_dimensions).  The example above will not jump at all.

Comment: I remembered that hyperref had its own page counter, but didn't realize it had more than one.

Comment: Thanks! But it will not compile because of "Undefined control sequence": `pagetop.\@the@H@page`. Looks like we are closer, though :)

Comment: Maybe this is something to take usage of: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55620/123984

Comment: I must be forgetting to run these things 3 times.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much!

I think you are capable of answering this question too: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285201/hyperlink-to-top-of-the-page-with-given-hypertarget