# Link to a section frame links to first page

Tags: beamer, xetex, hyperref

I want to link to a section frame from another frame. `\hyperref[label]{Text}` should do the job but it links to the first frame instead.

My MWE (using XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{fontspec}  

\begin{document}
\frame[plain,noframenumbering]{\maketitle}

\begin{frame}{TOC}
  \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections, sections={1-2}]       
  \hyperref[specialLink]{Special Link to Three}
  \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections, sections={4}]             
\end{frame}

\section{One}

\section{Two}

\section{Three}\label{specialLink}

\section{Four}

\end{document}
```

Update: Tried @samcarter's answer but the link now points between the first and second slide of a section. Updated MWE below:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{fontspec}  

\begin{document}
\frame[plain,noframenumbering]{\maketitle}

\begin{frame}{TOC}
  \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections, sections={1-2}]       
  \hyperlink{specialLink}{Special Link to Three}
  \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections, sections={4}]             
\end{frame}

\section{One}

\section{Two}

\section{Three}\label{specialLink}

\frame{a}
\frame{b}
\frame{c}
\frame{d}

\section{Four}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is `\hyperlink{label}{link text}`

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex


\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usepackage{fontspec}  

\begin{document}
\frame[plain,noframenumbering]{\maketitle}

\begin{frame}{TOC}
  \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections, sections={1-2}]   
  \hyperlink{specialLink}{link text}
  \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections, sections={4}]             
\end{frame}

\section{One}

\section{Two}

{
\addtobeamertemplate{section page}{\label{specialLink}}{}
\section{Three}
}


\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test2
\end{frame}

\section{Four}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This links to the last frame of the section.

Comment: @yoshegg Works fine for me

Comment: I was wrong, it points to somewhere between the first and second slide of a section. See my updated question for updated MWE.

Comment: @yoshegg With the position of your label it links to the first frame after the label. The section frame is already finished at the position you used the label.

Comment: Okay, I understand, I have to put it in front of the relevant `\section`. Now my pdf reader puts the text of the section slide on top, instead of the top of the section slide.

Comment: What I meant: Any idea on how to make this work they it works for the other sections?

Comment: @yoshegg have a look if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285201/hyperlink-to-top-of-the-page-with-given-hypertarget helps